# Java-Objective-C-Bridge how to create NSString**

Tags: java, objective-c, macos, jna

I am trying to call Native code from Java. (Both on Windows & a Mac) I am having difficulty doing this on a Mac because of the age of most packages.  I started by trying to write JINI code, found JNA it's easier for Windows/linux, tried Rococoa, and finally stumbled upon **Java-Object-C-Bridge** as a simple and lighter option for using JNA to call a Coca function on a Mac.

I want to call the Objective C  funciton

```
NSWorkspace

- (BOOL)getInfoForFile:(NSString *)fullPath
       application:(NSString * _Nullable *)appName
              type:(NSString * _Nullable *)type
```

I have been able to get JNA and **Java-Object-C-Bridge** to successfully work for other function calls.  But I can't call the function I need because I can't figure out how to configure the pointer to a pointer to pass into the code.

```
    Client client = Client.getInstance();
    Proxy client.sendProxy("NSWorkspace", "sharedWorkspace");
    ...
    Boolean rtn = workspace.sendBoolean("isFilePackageAtPath:", file);
    ...
    rtn = workspace.sendBoolean("getInfoForFile:", file, 
       appPtrPtr, typePtrPtr);
```

The call to "isFilePackageAtPath" works smoothly.  But I can't get the function I really want to work because I have no idea how to declare and initialize appPtrPtr or typePtrPtr.   I have tried making Pointer objects,  tried making them Pointer objects that point to Pointers & String. Tried JNA's  PointerByReference class.  I crash in one of the dynamic libraries and I can't find any documentation or examples.  I understand the problem, The objective-C function will needs to allocate the space for these strings and somehow pass me back a pointer to this string so that I can copy this string and release it's memory.  Tricky since Java doesn't work like this.

```
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  SIGSEGV (0xb) at pc=0x00007fff8cef7732, pid=63746, tid=6915
#
# JRE version: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (8.0_66-b17) (build 1.8.0_66-    b17)
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (25.66-b17 mixed mode bsd-amd64 compressed oops)
# Problematic frame:
# C  [libsystem_c.dylib+0x1732]  strlen+0x12
#
# Failed to write core dump. Core dumps have been disabled. To enable core dumping, try "ulimit -c unlimited" before starting Java again
```

Suggestions?  Examples?  I am hoping that "Steve Hannah" the developer for this package might be able to chime in.

Comment: `PointerByReference` is definitely the JNA answer.  Call `getValue()` on that after the call to get the "returned" pointer.

Comment: PointerByReference didn't work with this bridge package.    I finally gave up on using the **Java-Object-C-Bridge** code.    I wrote my own DynamicLibrary in XCode that could be called from JNA and it works well.  It's lighter than anything other than a straight JNI.  Since I wrote my own library I didn't pass it back with References.